# Maximum value of an array questions

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 10

int main() {
  int a[N], i, pos;

  printf("\n\nΕισαγωγή 10 ακεραίων\n");

  for (i=0; i<N; i++) {
    printf("%2d : ", i+1);
    scanf("%d", &a[i]);
  }

  pos = 0;

  for (i=1; i<N; i++) {
    if (a[pos] < a[i]){
      pos = i;
    }
  }

  printf("\n\nΗ μέγιστη τιμή είναι %d και βρέθηκε στη θέση %d\n\n", a[pos],pos+1);

  return 0;
}
```

This is the program/code that is found in my e-class' lectures.

The thing that literally makes no sense for me, first of all, is the `i++` as "change condition" in the two `for` loops. Normally/logically it is to be expected to add `pos` I twice until it reaches N, since we have two `for` loops and the `i+1` of printf in the first `for` loop which is also repeated and should be also repeated. Logically, doesn't that add the position-variable `i` thrice in the program every time?  Logically this is the thing is must do but when I run it this actually doesn't happen and it operates as we want it/expect it to.

Furthermore, I have queries about `a[pos]`. At the start it is `a[0]` and with `pos+1`. Since there is no position 0 and we start from `i+1` with the printf function then what is the position 0 and what is its value? Is `i=1` the position 0? Furthermore since we got `pos=i` then why does the final printf to print one position after this with `pos+1`? Considering that every time `a[pos]` is smaller than `a[i]` the position becomes equal with `i`.

Comment: The first loop just populates the array. Arrays in c start at index 0, but the programmer decided they wanted to show them as if starting at index 1, hence the i+1. The second loop finds the maximum by starting with the first array element, then updating pos every time it finds a larger integer. What don't you understand? This could be done in the one loop as it isn't necessary to keep all the inputted values in an array.

Answer (score 2):

Let's break down the code step by step to understand how it works:

1. The program starts by defining an array `a` of size `N` (which is 10 in this case) and two integer variables `i` and `pos`.
2. It then enters a loop to read 10 integers from the user and store them in the array `a`.
3. After reading the integers, it initializes `pos` to 0.
4. Then, it enters another loop starting from `i=1` to `N-1`, which is 9 in this case.
5. Inside this loop, it checks if the value of `a[pos]` (initially `a[0]`) is less than the value of `a[i]`. If it is, it updates `pos` to `i`.
6. After the loop completes, `pos` will hold the index of the maximum value in the array.
7. Finally, it prints out the maximum value (`a[pos]`) and its position (`pos+1`) in the array.

Now, let's address your specific concerns:

1. The `i++` statement in the for loops is just a standard increment of the loop variable `i`. It doesn't affect the behavior of the program in the way you described. In each iteration of the loop, `i` is incremented by 1, and this behavior is consistent with the typical usage of for loops in C.
2. The `pos` variable is used to store the index of the maximum value found so far. It is not added to `i` or anything like that. The `pos+1` in the final `printf` statement is used to display the position of the maximum value in a human-readable format, as array indices typically start from 0 in C. So, adding 1 to `pos` converts the zero-based index to a one-based index.

In summary, the code is correctly finding the maximum value in the array and printing its position. The increment of i and the use of `pos+1` in the final `printf` statement are consistent with standard C programming practices and do not affect the correctness of the program.

Comment: "the i++ statement in the for loops is just a standard increment of the loop variable i." I know that but still does that mean it is i1 and i2? Because if it is one i variable in the whole program and we have two i++ increments in two for repetition statements wouldn't that increase i every time? Except if it is i1 and i2 and the "for" statement are like little sandboxes. As for "pos+1"... I still didn't understand it because "pos=i" updates every time so why you will move it one position further? It updates to the final value and position of i as well.

Comment: "In each iteration of the loop, i is incremented by 1, and this behavior is consistent with the typical usage of for loops in C." Yeah but we got two loops in one "run"... Alright, then how do you explain the "i+1" in every loop? Doesn't "i+1", at least in display manner, gets repeated N times since it is permanently in printf? That means even if "i++" is only allowed to increase 1 every time in the whole code there is still the second "run" of the first loop "for" in which it would add i two times one in display as "i+1" and one in actuality/essence as "i++".